# Odoo: company_id in res.company showing non stored field while get data model to controller

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-view

odoo error : Not non stored filed country_id

@http.route('/home/', type='http', auth='public', website=True)
        def navigate_to_detail_page(self):
         obj = http.request.env['res.company'].sudo().search([])
         country_list = http.request.env['res.country'].sudo().search([])

Comment: Please write your code in code view. So, we can understand it's well.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have pass country name(from res.country) through post method(controller to model), in HTTP return it not able return any data from res.company(in terminal(res.company()). I have also try store=True with country_id field. Right now i am unable to send same data. I hope you will able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object of res.company in HTTP controller. Like the following:

```
company = request.env.user.company_id
```

In the company variable, you can get the object of res.company of the current login user.

I hope this helps you. Thank you.